# Finding a complete repository for Gradle Dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm using Gradle version `7.0.2` in Android Studio. My project needs `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'` in `build.gradle` file.
So Gradle must download the `gradle-7.0.2.pom`, but it can't since none of the repositories has this file except for `google()`, which gives error 404.
Can you tell me the name of the repository which has this file?

I looked for `mavenCentral()`, but it doesn't support gradle `7.0.2`.

Comment: Could you add more details to your question? It's hard to understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: My problem is fixed. Changing the browser I'm using fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use another browser such as *Opera Mini*. Use the website [MVNRepository](https://www.mvnrepository.com) to browse Google Maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

some options:

- you are under a proxy and it do not allow the communication. Try to disable any vpn and, if it still do not work, connect the device to another internet connection. I tried and the resource is downloaded from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip Also trying to browse the resource the zip file is downloaded
- the problem is about a compatibility among the 2 libraries - see
  https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin. If you go to file > Project Structure > Project, what are the values selected for "Android Gradle Plugin Version" and "Gradle Version"?